# posting content automatically with login

Tags: xml, automation, posting

I'm trying to submit content to a website on behalf of a client. Most similar websites will allow me to integrate by sending them an XML feed and automatically posting but this particular site wants a ton of money for this simply integration.

I'm wondering if there's a service out there that can log in to my client's account and then post the content.

We have multiple clients that want to use the site and the posting process is always the same, so I'd imagine there's a way to get this done... but I'm not a technical person. Any help would be greatly appreciated!